# system MemoryMax by percentage not working?

Tags: systemd, cgroups, ulimit, out-of-memory

I am trying to configure my .service file to limit how much memory a given service can use up before being terminated, by percentage of system memory (10% as an upper limit in this case):

```
[Unit]
Description=MQTT Loop
After=radioLoop.service

[Service]
Type=simple
Environment=PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 -u /opt/pilot/mqttLoop.py
WorkingDirectory=/opt/pilot
StandardOutput=journal
Restart=on-failure
User=pilot
MemoryMax=10%

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The line of interest is the `MemoryMax` line, which I've tried to configured based on my understanding of [the systemd docs](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.resource-control.html).

My version of systemd is:

```
systemd 241 (241)
+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +IMA +APPARMOR +SMACK +SYSVINIT +UTMP +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +GNUTLS +ACL +XZ +LZ4 +SECCOMP +BLKID +ELFUTILS +KMOD -IDN2 +IDN -PCRE2 default-hierarchy=hybrid
```

But it does not work.

```
# ps -m -o lwp,rss,pmem,pcpu,unit -u pilot
  LWP   RSS %MEM %CPU UNIT
    - 76244 30.3  8.5 mqttLoop.service
 1232     -    -  7.0 mqttLoop.service
 1249     -    -  1.7 mqttLoop.service
 1254     -    -  0.2 mqttLoop.service
```

I'm getting well above 10% (30% there), and then it does not restart the process. I've tried exchanging `MemoryMax` for `MemoryLimit` (the older variant of same value), but it has no effect. What am I missing?

### UPDATE

I have determined that the systemd settings for processing counting are correctly turned on.

```
# grep -i "memory" system.conf
#DefaultMemoryAccounting=yes
```

But I note the following in my kernel configuration:

[image]

Will it be enough that I rebuild my kernel with the `Memory Controller` option selected?

Comment: What does `systemctl status «whatever».service` give? In particular,what does the `Memory:` line show? BTW: That won't actually terminate the service, it will instead prevent it from using more memory. Which may mean it swaps instead.

Comment: That's the weird thing. In the examples I found, their status showed a Memory: line. But mine doesn't. But I also note that the terms from the examples have changed from MemoryLimit to MemoryMax. So I don't know whether a) my setting of the value is being ignored because I'm missing some kernel support or other configuration or b) because systemctl status output has changed.

Comment: Also, from the systemd docs, it says `Specify the absolute limit on memory usage of the executed processes in this unit. If memory usage cannot be contained under the limit, out-of-memory killer is invoked inside the unit.` That sounds like it **kills** it to me...?

Comment: The lack of a Memory: line seems to say memory accounting isn't enabled. It needs to be enabled in the kernel config (and possibly on the kernel command line, depending). It also needs to be enabled by systemd; you could try setting `DefaultMemoryAccounting=yes` in `/etc/systemd/system.conf` (and then rebooting).

Comment: How to set the   kernel configuration? witch command should I  use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, turning that option on was enough to enable the MemoryMax to work as expected.

Comment: How to turn that option on?

Comment: Edit `/etc/systemd/system.conf` and make sure there's no `#` on the line `DefaultMemoryAccounting=yes` and reboot the system if you had to modify that config.